# How to check the credentials received from android UsernamePasswordCredentials using php

Tags: php, android, httpclient

I have written below code in android to communicate with server, but I don't know how to check the credentials supplied by android app by `UsernamePasswordCredentials` java class using PHP. Please help ...

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

                //Setup timeouts
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 15000);

                UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials("myUserName", "myPassword");
                ConnectionClient client = new ConnectionClient(creds);

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2:8888/c5/login.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httppost);
                //HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Comment: Refer this [android php webservice](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/267023/Send-and-receive-json-between-android-and-php) and [android-mysql-php-json-tutorial](http://codeoncloud.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-mysql-php-json-tutorial.html)

Comment: I am stuck please help ...